# R : moving text from one cell to another, without deleting original content

Tags: r, dataframe, cell

Is it possible in R to move the text content of a cell without deleting the content of the second cell ?

Indeed, if I do the following, the original content of "f_com" (supposed it is "blibli") is replaced. I would like to have "blablabla blibli".

```
DF0 [DF0$record_id =="2004", "f_com"] <- "blablabla"
```

Comment: Try `DF0 [DF0$record_id =="2004", "f_com"] <- paste("blablabla", DF0 [DF0$record_id =="2004", "f_com"], sep = " ")` Thanks @Friede